# Maximize event on .NET compact framework

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have created a fullscreen application in C# .NET Compact Framework for Windows CE. My customer would like to use a function key to minimize the app. I have bound F2 to this key using the following code:

```
private void Minimize()
{
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    this.ControlBox = true;
    this.MinimizeBox = true;
    this.MaximizeBox = true;
    ShowWindow(this.Handle, SW_MINIMIZED);
}
```

ShowWindow is an external method from the "coredll.dll" file. Because the "coredll" file cannot minimize an app without ControlBoxes I have to show them before I minimize.

However when the user maximizes the application again, I would like to undo everything I did before the external call in the Minimize method. How would I do this? I do not see an "OnMaximize" event in on the form? Any help would be greatly appreciated :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not try this but as I can remember OnActivated or OnShow are executed when maximizing the window.

Comment: Thank you! Activated did, however it also fires at other times. I just added a bool that is set to true when the app is being minimized, and use that to check if the event should be run.